# Error while trying to run project uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I have installed `Visual studio 2010` Ultimate verion but while running below simple windows form programme getting error....

```
    MsgBox("Hello !")

    "error while trying to run project uncaught exception thrown by method called 
     through reflection"
```

anything wrong with installation ??

Its Visula studio Exception not my programme exception...

I tried below but no luck..

```
devenv /resetsettings
```

[image]

Comment: if you `Catch` the exception, what is the `InnerException`? and the `InnerException`'s `InnerException`, etc

Comment: Gravell, I know exception handling...I have fresh install on new machine and not able to run anytype of programme. I tried below as well..  Try
            MsgBox("OK")

        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.ToString())

        End Try

Comment: For what it's worth, I'm getting this while running in safemode in an attempt to troubleshoot another issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if it is a problem with the installation then I would recommend reinstalling. :(

Maybe try checking for updates and/or restarting your PC. If you still can't run your projects then I would recommend re-installing.

Comment: yes, last option was that only and it worked..but still not sure what went wrong..I was looking for root cause ...

Comment: Sorry, I am not too familiar with the inner workings of Visual Studio. Hopefully someone can give some more information as to why the problem happened in the first place. I'm sure there are log files kept somewhere that may provide some more information.

Comment: I am also interested in the 'root' cause. However not the root, but one "upperlevel" cause in my case was disabling the native code debuging myself (as noted in the answer below by `GallDude33`). Anyway I did never expect that could cause this problem.

Comment: Using the "repair" option instead of re-installing (on VS2012) worked for me.

Answer (score 29):

1. Go to the project right click and select properties.
2. Select 'Debug' tab on the left.
3. Go to ‘Enable Debuggers’ on the bottom
4. Check ‘Enable Native code debugging’ (or 'Enable unmanaged code debugging', depends on version) check box
5. Run the project

Comment: @GalDude33: Thanks, this worked for me as well (and so weired as well). Do you have any info why this should cause the problem. Anyway I did't want to debug or even load symbols of unmanaged/native parts of my program but this option forces me. Thanks anyway.

Comment: This worked for me as well in VS 2017; very strange, but I"ll take it.

Comment: I had to restart Visual Studio after checking the 'Native Code' box for my ASP.NET MVC application.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Steps to your problem]

I have uploaded the steps to your problem.

As you see the image, check the native code debugging option and that's all.

Hope it helps.

I'm using Visual Studio 2017

Answer (score 3):

## This is an annoying problem.

If you **Enable native code Debugging** then you cannot Edit-and-Continue:

> Changes are not allowed when unmanaged debugging is enabled.

I finally solved it by unticking **Enable native code Debugging**  and unticking **Enable IntelliTrace**

[image]

---

Another time I got this error was when I upgraded a Solution from VS2010 to VS2017.

The problem was the Setup Project hadn't been set to the GUI (it was set to a Control Class Library):

The solution is to right click the Project > Set as StartUp Project:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @Jeremy thompson, Though this was not the cause, I will still keep this in mind. Nice catch !

Answer (score 1):

I just had to restart vs. As right clicking the solution was giving the same error.

Answer (score -1):

Restarting Visual Studio fixed this for me.