# Uncaught exception thrown by method called through reflection

Tags: visual-studio-2012, compiler-errors

What does this error mean? I am currently using Windows 8 and installed Microsoft Visual Studio 2012 Ultimate. The first time I installed vs2012 there were no errors. However, when I modified the settings in msconfig, which returned to its default after restarting the computer, there were compatiily issues with vs2012. I don't know how to uninstall vs2012 because there are several applications included in the entire package of installing vs2012. I uninstalled VS2012 application but it was not effectively removed from my computer. I reinstalled vs 2012 using a different installer which enabled me to read my source codes. However when I ran the program this error occurred. How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

1. Go to the project right click and select properties.
2. Select 'Debug' tab on the left.
3. Go to ‘Enable Debuggers’ on the bottom
4. Check ‘Enable Native code debugging’ (or 'Enable unmanaged code debugging', depends on version) check box
5. Run the project! =]

Comment: As suggested by answers to [error-while-trying-to-run-project-uncaught-exception-thrown-by-method-called-thr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17146438/error-while-trying-to-run-project-uncaught-exception-thrown-by-method-called-thr) @GalDude33 response didn't work in all situations.
I had to use VS2012 "repair" option through windows control panel to fix this issue. I didn't have to do a full re-install.

Comment: What if it is a web project? There is no "Debug" tab on the properties.

Comment: @blaise in "Web" tab there is "Native Code" checkbox.